# How to write a SQL-Query for the following table?

Tags: sql

My table is defined like this:

Name is a string and property too.

```
ID | Name | Property
```

An example for data in this table is this:

```
ID | Name | Property
1    Peter  Newsletter
2    Paul   Register
3    Peter  Register
4    Shaun  Newsletter
5    Steve  Register
```

Now I like to query all people that have the property newsletter and register.
As a result I should get Peter, because he has both property's.

So the resulting table should be like:

```
ID | Name | Property
1    Peter  Newsletter
3    Peter  Register
```

So everything I try to query is which person has both property's newsletter and register.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is one method:

```
select t.*
from table t
where exists (select 1
              from table t2
              where t2.name = t.name and t2.property = 'NewsLetter'
             ) and
      exists (select 1
              from table t2
              where t2.name = t.name and t2.property = 'Register'
             );
```

If you just want the list of names, perhaps with `id`s, I would do that as:

```
select t.name
from table t
where t2.property in ('NewsLetter', 'Register')
group by t.name
having count(distinct property) = 2;
```

How you get the list of `id`s depends on your database, something like `listagg()` or `group_concat()` or `string_agg()`.

Answer (score 2):

An alternative, pretty much on the same lines as Gordon's solution, but without using `EXISTS`:

```
select * from tablename
where name in (select name from tablename where property = 'Newsletter')
and name in (select name from tablename where property = 'Register')
```

Comment: I will try both of your approaches, now Im stuck in something else. Give me some time and I will reward the best working approach with accepting it as solution =) Thanks so far

Answer (score 1):

It's hard to be sure without knowing more about the data. Given the exact requirements that you gave to us, this will give the results you showed:

```
WITH multprop (multName) AS (
   SELECT NAME FROM myTable
       WHERE Property IN('Newsletter','Register')
       GROUP BY NAME
       HAVING count(*)>1 )
select id, Name, Property
 from multprop inner join myTable
      on multName = Name
```

But minor differences in your requirements will mess things up. For example, will there **ever be** Property values other than the two you listed? Or can a Name show up multiple times with the same Property?

EDIT: The added WHERE clause limits rows in the CTE to the requested specific set of `Property` values. This is from the more detailed requirements in comments.

Comment: There are more property's than the two I listed, but this two are the one that are interesting for me. A name can not show up multiple times with the same property.

Comment: Your comment narrows the possibilities, so a WHERE clause now limits rows in the CTE (Common Table Expression, i.e., the `WITH` clause). Using a CTE is an alternative syntax that's well worth learning. The `IN()` predicate could be a _sub-select_ instead of an explicit list so that the desired `Property` list could be from a temporary table.

Answer (score 1):

One more way:

```
SELECT * FROM T as T1
WHERE Property IN ('Newsletter','Register')
      AND EXISTS (SELECT * FROM T 
                      WHERE Name=T1.Name 
                            and Property IN ('Newsletter','Register')
                            and Property <> T1.Property
                 )
```

<kbd>[SQLFiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/1caf13/1)</kbd>

Answer (score 1):

Another one, for the record

```
WITH cteHasBoth
 as (select Name
       from MyTable
       where Property in ('Newsletter', 'Register')
       group by Name
       having count(*) = 2)
 select ID, Name
  from MyTable
  where name in (select Name from cteHasBoth)
```

This would require only two sacns through the table.